# Find all the number in this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

We need to find all elements in this recurrent series:
$X_{i+1} = \frac{X_{i}^3 + 2}{3X_{i}^2}$
i vary from 1 to 2020
$X_{1} = X_{2021}$

"Find all real and positive $(X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{2021})$ "

I could see that Xi = 1 for all i is a possible solution

Maybe there is other solution, but i am not sure

Comment: I suggest to study $(X_i-1)/(X_1-1)$ when $i$ is odd.

Comment: @Somos Hi. thank you. I am still having trouble to evaluate what you said. The algebra is getting bigger and bigger, so i thought that i am going by the wrong way.

Could you say more one tip?

Comment: Okay, here is a tip. Define $\,f(x):=(x^3+2)/(3x^2).\,$ To show that $\,f(f(x))=x\,$ has only one solution for $\,x>0\,$ it is enough to show that $\,x-f(f(x))\,$ is an increasing function. You can do that by showing the derivative is positive. This derivative factors and you can show that the factor $\,4+22x^3+x^6>0\,$ for $\,>0.$